# Publishing React Component on npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I developed a react component and I am now trying to publish it on NPM for over a week now. Unfortunately, I'm facing challenges and couldn't find credible resources online to guide me through the process.

Could someone please provide step-by-step guidance or point me to reliable resources for publishing a React component on NPM? I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights from those who have experience with this process.

Thank you in advance!

I tried using storybook but that does not let us push our component to npm, react's documentation asks us to use 'nwb' for publishing components on NPM but it is deprecated and libraries similar to 'nwb' like 'create react library' and 'tsdx' are also deprecated. I also tried publishing the builds of rollup and webpack, that didn't work either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled too last summer to make it work.

Here are some links that helped me to achieve that but none of them were really suitable for what I needed. So I think you have to find your solution on your own and probably this will be the best even for you.

Give it a try to this guides? They seems straight forward to follow.
They are also updated to the 2022.

https://dev.to/femi_dev/how-to-build-and-publish-your-first-react-npm-package-24o3

regarding the component library you can use this guide as well

https://www.airplane.dev/blog/how-to-build-a-react-component-library

Last spring I was able to publish my first component library following this guide. Of course I changed somethings as i mention above but I was able to make it work and use it on a nextjs projects.

https://prateeksurana.me/blog/react-component-library-using-storybook-7/

I hope these links will help you, maybe all together they will guide you to find by yourself a solution and you will learn more then just following a step by step guide.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).